# TcPDF generates pdf that corrupts in adobe reader

Tags: php, pdf, export, tcpdf, fpdf

Using the TcPDF PHP class I generate a pdf and the 'special' functions i use are:

- `addTTFfont` (add custom font)
- `ImageSVG` (add svg)
- `Image`
- `writeHTMLCell`

The output pdf opens correctly in Foxit reader, and Mac Premier.
But Adobe reader has a process AcroRd32.exe that takes in an inifinite amount of working memory and nothing responds, after which I need to reboot the computer.
When I remove the custom font, it does open, but crashes soon after. It seems that the html cells give an error too...

Googling around I have seen suggestions to change the import of TTF from truetype to truetypeunicode. That didn't help.

Does anyone have experience with this? Why is this only seen with Acrobat reader?

Comment: Please supply a sample PDF for inspection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed. Apparently the problem was that the font that was converted to the right tcPdf format on the fly while generating, was created incorrectly causing the corrupt file. But when I converted it manually in another service (I used http://www.xml-convert.com/en/convert-tff-font-to-afm-pfa-fpdf-tcpdf) and stored te files in the tcPdf fonts folder, it did work (just request the fonts the same way the other pre-installed fonts are requested)

Comment: did same but still causing issue